# Spring-boot - save ArrayList in dynamodb using crudrepository

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am using `Dynamodb` with `spring-boot` in local environment. When I try to save List of object using `repository.save()`, where repository type extends `CrudRepository` interface, I am getting below exception:

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException:
>   Class class java.util.ArrayList must be annotated with interface
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable

Is it not possible to save List of objects using CrudRepository like in MongoRepository we can save List of objects.

Answer (score 1):

May be not, as List may contain duplicate records where DynamoDB is expecting unique set of records. Please use Set instead of List then it should work. Please use the following annotation on your DB model object -

```
@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.L)
private Set<MyObject> myObjSet = new HashSet<>();
```

Also use `@DynamoDBDocument` annotation at the class level at MyObject.java.
Then it should work.